# Do we say “quatre fichiers” or “quatres fichiers”?

Tags: pluriel, nombres

I would like to say “*J'ai organisé le code source en 4 fichiers*”. Should “*quatre*” be written with an “s” or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Citons le [Projet Voltaire](http://www.projet-voltaire.fr/blog/regle-orthographe/%C2%AB-quatre-%C2%BB-ou-%C2%AB-quatres-%C2%BB) :

> À l’exception de « vingt » et de « cent », qui peuvent être multipliés, les adjectifs numéraux cardinaux (quatre, cinq, huit, douze, etc.) sont invariables, même quand ils sont utilisés comme des noms :
>
> > les cinq de cœur, les quarante voleurs, les sept péchés capitaux, etc.
>
> En ce qui concerne « un », on ne confondra pas le pronom indéfini, variable, avec le nom, invariable. Si l’on est évidemment fondé à écrire : « Les uns sont partis, les autres sont restés », on se gardera de mettre la marque du pluriel dans cet autre cas : « Il dessinait ses un comme des sept, ce qui lui valait les reproches de son patron ».

---

English translation:

With the exception of "vingt" and "cent", which can be multiplied, cardinal numeral adjectives (quatre, cinq, huit, douze, etc.) are invariable, even when they are used as nouns:

> les cinq de cœur, les quarante voleurs, les sept péchés capitaux, etc.

Regarding "un", the indefinite pronoun agrees in number whereas the noun does not. If one is of course entitled to write: "Les *uns* sont partis, les autres sont restés," we will keep to the plural in the other cases: "Il dessinait ses *un* comme des sept, ce qui lui valait les reproches de son patron."

Answer (score 0):

While *quatre* is invariable so you can only say *quatre fichiers*,  an euphonic 's' sometimes appears in spoken French after an apocoped *quatre* (*quat'*) like in the following expressions :

> les quat'z'arts (École des Beaux-Arts)
>
> les quat'z'amis

and the popular

> entre quat'z'yeux (face to face / one to one meeting)

Note that the 's' est transcripted with a 'z' to preserve the sound it must have in a liaison.

---

Bien que *quatre* soit invariable et que seul « quatre fichiers » soit correct, un 's' euphonique apparaît parfois après un « quatre » apocopé en « quat' » comme dans ces expressions :

> les quat'z'arts (École des Beaux-Arts)
>
> les quat'z'amis

et le très courant:

> entre quat'z'yeux

Note: Le 's' est transcrit en 'z' pour préserver le son qu'il doit avoir dans une liaison.

Answer (score -1):

"Quatre" is a number and can't take any S.
The only time you can add an "s" to a number is when you use "-", like in "quatre-vingts" (80).

Comment: That’s unclear. One write “huit cents”, but “quatre-vingt-trois“.